# Access of Undefined property oneSecTimer

Tags: flash, timer

I really have no clue what's wrong. I continue to get the same error over and over again. Access of undefined property OneSecTimer for lines 31, 32 and 46. This is my first time coding with Flash so I honestly have no clue what's going on here. The OnTimeComplete is suppose to be private, but is that why things aren't be accessed?

package  {

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;


public class MainTimer extends MovieClip {
    // Init vars for class
    private var currentMin:int;
    private var currentSec:int;
    // create a one second timer from Flash's Timer class
    private var onSecTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);            

    public var timerHasStopped:Boolean = false;

    public function MainTimer() {
        // constructor code
        trace("the main timer is here");
        currentMin= 2;
        currentSec = 5;

        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        if(currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }else{
            secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        }

        oneSecTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
        oneSecTimer.start();
    }

    private function onTimerComplete(event:TimerEvent):void{
        currentSec = currentSec - 1;
        if (currentSec < 0){
            currentSec = 59;
            currentMin -= 1;
        } //end if
        if(currentMin < 0){
            currentMin = 0;
            currentSec = 0;
            timerHasStopped = true;
        }else{
            oneSecTimer.start();
        } //end else

        //update the display
        minBox.text = String(currentMin);
        secBox.text = String(currentSec);
        if(currentSec < 10){
            secBox.text = "0" + String(currentSec);
        }//end if                

    }//end function 

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a spelling error

```
private var onSecTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
```

Should be

```
private var oneSecTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,1);
```

(You're missing an `e`)

When you get an error about a missing property, the first thing you should generally do is go to where you think you defined it and make sure it is defined there exactly the way you expected it to be :)

Comment: -______________- Oh god I feel stupid. This keyboard has bad ghosting. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I will, I have to wait 8 minutes haha